How do I change the signing algorithm of JWT token on auth JS
I found this info from the documentation: The JWT issued by Auth.js is encrypted by default, using the A256CBC-HS512 algorithm (JWE). It uses the AUTH_SECRET environment variable or the passed secret property to derive a suitable encryption key.
I am wondering how to change the algorithm e.g. to RS256. I am using CredentialsProvider - according to chatgpt, this is what I am supposed to use:
import NextAuth from 'next-auth';
import CredentialsProvider from 'next-auth/providers/credentials';

const options = {
  providers: [
    CredentialsProvider({
      // other options
      signingAlgorithm: 'RS256', // or 'HS256' or 'ES256', depending on the algorithm you want to use
    }),
    // other providers
  ],
};

export default NextAuth(options);

But this does not seem to work on the current release of Auth.JS.

You can override the default JWE algorithm by using the encode and decode methods

To be note that RS256 is a signature algorithm and not am encryption one.

I finally came up with this:
jwt: {
        encode:async ({secret, token}) =>{
          if (!secret){
            return ""
          }
           return jwt.sign({ ...token, userId: token?.sub }, secret as jwt.Secret, {
            algorithm: "HS256",
            expiresIn: 30 * 24 * 60 * 60,
          })
        },
          decode: async ({ secret, token }) => {
            if (!secret){
            return null
            }
          return jwt.verify(token!, secret as jwt.Secret, { algorithms: ["HS256"] }) as jwt.JwtPayload
        },
      },

